# Is it possible to have Excel return a date when counting down to a date from a specific date that is NOT today or now?

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Is it possible to have Excel return a date when counting down to a date from a specific date that is NOT today or now? 
Ex: End_date is 04/22/14 and data that I have is "2 weeks before", "3 days before", "4 months before", etc. So I want the cells with "3 days before" to display the date (04/19/14)

I've found info on counting down from today:
=DATEVALUE("22-April-2014")-TODAY()&" days remaining"

but this displays the time remaining and I need the TODAY to be replaced with a value that represents "2 weeks before" April 22 AND for the return to be a dat

This may not be possible :/

Comment: "2 weeks before": just subtract 14. And so on.

Comment: hi, i think what you're asking is just simple but I can't understand what you want to achieve? Can you explain further? As momobo commented out, you only need to add/subtract a whole number on date values to display days before or after.

Comment: I have almost achieved what you want. I am just struggling with options like `1 month before`, `2 years before`. Would you be having month and years in those text? If not then it is very simple

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comment above, since your post doesn't mention that you will have text like `1 month before` or `2 years before`, I am going to assume that they are not there. If they are then we will have to slightly tweak the formula.

Let's say your data looks like this (Ignore the cells in red. I am still experimenting with it)

[image]

Simply add this formula in Cell `B2` and pull it down

`=(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1)))*(VLOOKUP(TRIM(MID(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1),SEARCH(" ",A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1)+1)-SEARCH(" ",A2,1))),F:G,2,0))`

and this in `C2` and pull it down

`=DATEVALUE("22-April-2014")-B2`

Also Add a small table for lookup in column `F:J` as shown in the image below

[image]

**Explanation**

I am using `Left/Search/Mid` to extract the numerical part and the text after that which could be `Day/week/Days/weeks/fortnight/fortnights/Months/Years/Month/Year` and then using a Vlookup to find the equivalent in days.

So if I break this `=(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1)))*(VLOOKUP(TRIM(MID(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1),SEARCH(" ",A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1)+1)-SEARCH(" ",A2,1))),F:G,2,0))` up for the first cell, I get

`(LEFT(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1)))` = 3 and
`(VLOOKUP(TRIM(MID(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1),SEARCH(" ",A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1)+1)-SEARCH(" ",A2,1))),F:G,2,0))` = 7

and hence = 3*7 =21

`(VLOOKUP(TRIM(MID(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1),SEARCH(" ",A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1)+1)-SEARCH(" ",A2,1))),F:G,2,0))` can be further broken up

`TRIM(MID(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1),SEARCH(" ",A2,SEARCH(" ",A2,1)+1)-SEARCH(" ",A2,1)))` will give you `Weeks` and once we know that we do a simple lookup.

**Challenges**

Like I mentioned, if you have months and days then there can be multiple values for them. See the table.

Comment: Hi Sid, can you please explain how `1 month before` value is `28` and `25/03/2014`. i think it should be `22/03/2014`. I am trying but strucked while considering the month(28-feb,29-feb leap,30-apr,sep,nov.., 31 fro jan, dec..).

Comment: As mentioned in my post above month/year calculation (IN RED) are just for display purpose. I will work on it post OP's clarification. Right now it is just picking up values from the the first column of the vlookup table i.e `28`.

Answer (score 0):

If the text consists `days,weeks,months and years` then this solution helps.

in cloumn *`C`* add formula **`==MID(A1,FIND(" ", A1)+1,3)`** and drag it down.
in column *`B`* add formula **`=IF((C1="day"),($B$1-LEFT(A5,1)),IF(C1="wee",($B$1-(LEFT(A5,1)*7)),IF(C1="mon",EDATE($B$1,-LEFT(A5,1)),IF(C1="yea",EDATE($B$1,(-LEFT(A5,1)*12)))))`** and drag it down.

If `EDATE()` function is not available, and returns the #NAME? error means install and load the Analysis ToolPak add-in.

visit [HERE](http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/load-the-analysis-toolpak-HP010021569.aspx) to Load Analysis ToolPak for Excel.

Below is the snap shot of solution.

[image]

Comment: Your `=MID(A2,3,3)` formula will fail if A2 has say `33 days` or `101 days`

Comment: Nice sid, i didn't think about it. I updated my solution now.